# media player does not work in my code

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

### Listview with audios does not play

Hello how are you?
I'm trying to make a listview of audios everything seems to flow as it should, but when I click on a listitem the audio should reproduce but instead it appears "the app stopped working" I do not understand what's wrong with my code someone can help me I'm at times breaking my head but I can not solve this problem. Below is the logcat, and then my code, please someone help me make it work.
-Thank you

[Logcat](https://gist.github.com/welyson205/0325d950c15ade44de0ef1bda0aa25c8)

### MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView lv;
    MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.memes_main);

        lv = findViewById(R.id.lv);
        mp = new MediaPlayer();

        ArrayList<memes> item = new ArrayList<>();

        item.add(new memes("Gemidão", R.raw.gemidaoremix));
        item.add(new memes("Nunca nem vi", R.raw.nuncanemvi));


        ArrayAdapter<memes> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, item);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, item));

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                playSong(position);

            }
        });
    }


    public void playSong(int songIndex) {

        mp.reset();
        int[] resID = new int[0];
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resID[songIndex]);

        mp.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mp.release();
    }


    }
```

### memes.class

```
public class memes{

    private String nome;
    private int resID;

    memes(String nome, int resID){

        this.nome = nome;
        this.resID = resID;
    }

    public String getNome(){
        return nome;
    }

    public int getResId(){
        return resID;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return nome;
    }

}
```

Comment: The int array `int[] resID = new int[0];` is empty. That why you are getting `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: how should the code be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are declaring a separate array of raw resource which is not populated.

```
int[] resID = new int[0];
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resID[songIndex]);
```

**Solution**

Since you are using arraylist to populate the ListView,you need to fetch the resource from the Arraylist itself. The solution will be like this :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView lv;
    MediaPlayer mp;
    ArrayList<Memes> item;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lv = findViewById(R.id.lv);
        mp = new MediaPlayer();

        item = new ArrayList<>();

        item.add(new Memes("Gemidão", R.raw.gemidaoremix));
        item.add(new Memes("Nunca nem vi", R.raw.nuncanemvi));


        ArrayAdapter<Memes> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, item);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, item));

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                playSong(position);

            }
        });
    }

    public void playSong(int songIndex) {
        mp.reset();
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, item.get(songIndex).getResId());
        mp.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mp.release();
    }


}
```

Comment: thank you, this time looking for the solution, now finally I can put my searchview

Answer (score 1):

Use code like below:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);
```

to play:

```
mediaPlayer.start();
```

to pause:

```
mediaPlayer.pause();
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to work on the resource files , you can create another method that fills your list of songs , your problem comes from the `int[] resID = new int[0];`
 you are using an empty array.

see also [Supported Media Formats](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html)

***ADD***

`int[] songs={R.raw.gemidaoremix,R.raw.nuncanemvi};`

use `songs` as a playlist

***UPDATE***

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView lv;
    MediaPlayer mp;
    int[] songs={R.raw.gemidaoremix,R.raw.nuncanemvi};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lv = findViewById(R.id.lv);
        mp = new MediaPlayer();

        ArrayList<memes> item = new ArrayList<>();

        item.add(new memes("Gemidão", R.raw.gemidaoremix));
        item.add(new memes("Nunca nem vi", R.raw.nuncanemvi));


        ArrayAdapter<memes> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, item);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, item));

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
                playSong(position);

            }
        });
    }


public void playSong(int songIndex) {

    mp.reset();
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, songs[songIndex]);

    mp.start();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mp.release();
}
```

}